# Jquery or Javascript : Insert text into a textbox inside a cloned div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with button and text box. With the help of jquery I created its clone div. How can I add text to the cloned div text box?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#click").click(function () {
                cloneCount = cloneCount + 1;
                var clone=$("#dynamicDiv").clone(true);
                clone.show();
                var id=clone.attr('id', 'dynamicDiv' + cloneCount).insertAfter("#dynamicDiv");
                clone.css('display', 'inlineblock');
                clone.appendTo("#divHolderFirstModule");


               //how to add text in a textbox inside a cloned div?



            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
clone.find('input[type="text"]').val('new value');
```

Comment: i have used asp:textbox.. and how can I change the Id of the asp:textbox inside a div after creating clone of div???

Comment: and how can i add text into the textbox with new id ??

Comment: I am doing this but text is appearing in one line...how can i display it in multiple lines?

using textmode=multiline cause textbox empty .....

clone.find('input[type="text"]').attr('id', 'textbox' + cloneCount).val('yasir \n\r yasir');

Comment: try this code:-`var textarea=$('<textarea/>',{id:'textbox' + cloneCount});
textarea.val('yasir \n\r yasir');
var txt= clone.find('input[type="text"]');
txt.after(textarea);
txt.remove();`

Comment: `var textarea=$('<textarea/>',{id:'textbox' + cloneCount,readonly:'reasonly'}); `

Answer (score 1):

If some text needs to be added then can use [`.val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)

```
clone.find('input:text').val(function(index, value){
    return value + 'New text Value'; //Manipulate here
});
```

To simply updated its value use

```
clone.find('input:text').val('new text');
```

Comment: i have used asp:textbox..
and how can I  change the Id of the asp:textbox inside a div after creating clone of div???